# passing two arrays to a function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, function

I have a function that was working with one array.  Now I need to update it and pass it two arrays, and potentially perhaps three.  All arrays will always be the same length.

I added result2 and this isn't working.

```
displayCars();

function displayCars () {

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : '/modules/crm/selector-ajax.php',
        data : {
            'action' : 'get-images'
        },
success : function(result, result2) {

            var selectorDiv = $('#boat_isotope_gallery');
            var resultArray = $.parseJSON(result);
            var resultArray2 = $.parseJSON(result2);
```

My AJAX call is getting errors as well:

```
echo json_encode($isotopecubes).json_encode($isotopecubes2);
```

I tried the recommendation below as suggested and am getting uncaught syntax error of 'o' if I have the dataType:'json', line in, and 'u' if I comment it out.

My revised code is:

```
displayCars();

function displayCars () {

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : '/modules/crm/selector-ajax.php',
        data : {
            'action' : 'get-images'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data) {
       var result1 = data.isotopecubes;
       var result2 = data.isotopecubes2;
       var selectorDiv = $('#boat_isotope_gallery');
       var resultArray = $.parseJSON(result1);
       var resultArray2 = $.parseJSON(result2);
```

My Ajax call is now:

```
$result = array(
"isotopecubes" => $isotopecubes,
"isotopecubes2" => $isotopecubes2
);

echo json_encode($result);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, you can only receive **one** result from an ajax call, so you should join the arrays on the serverside and send them as one

```
$result = array(
    "isotopecubes1" => $isotopecubes,
    "isotopecubes2" => $isotopecubes2
);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Then just catch that on the clientside

```
function displayCars () {

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : '/modules/crm/selector-ajax.php',
        data : {
            'action' : 'get-images'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {
           var result1 = data.isotopecubes1;
           var result2 = data.isotopecubes2;

       ...........
```

Comment: I tried that and it is giving me an Uncaught Syntax Error: unexpected token o

Comment: And where did you see `$.parseJSON` in my code? Drop that, it's parsed automatically when the dataType is set to `json`